# Android library engineering

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

**Intro**: I have a native library (C++) with Java (JNI) wrapper. The library engine is cpu intensive, we don't want more than one app linking this lib to be running at the same time, and complex objects should be returned by the lib engine.

**The question**: What is the best way to engineer such an Android library?

So far, I could find just find 2 valuable examples: *OpenCV manager* and *Connectbot ssh-agent*.

I can think of a few solutions:

- **Solution 1**: Make a (bound or AIDL) service that wraps the library functionality. (should the service run in its own space? or in the space of the application that links to it? how can the native lib be loaded if it's in a different app space(`System.load("/data/data/com.company.myLib/lib.so")`). How to return complex objects in AIDL?). This should be the Connectbot way.
- **Solution 2**: Divide the lib into 2 components:

  1. A standalone package which keeps the native libs + a manager service
  2. An android lib-project which only contains Java wrappers which users can use to build their apps.

  This should be the OpenCV manager way. I don't know exactly the details, but this way one does not need a service to interface with and can just `import com.company.myLib.LibWrapper`. On the other side the LibWrapper class should perform `System.load("/data/data/com.company.myLib/lib.so")`. Correct?

I would personally go for solution 2. Unfortunately Android is a new land and there are not many models yet on how to develop a library. Is there any other/better solutions? Is there other considerations to make?

Comment: The decisive question, in my humble opinion, is what delivery model you want for your library. Will it be updated with the apps that make use of it, or it can be downloaded and upgraded independently?

Comment: @Alex Cohn: possibly independently upgraded/downloaded. Good consideration btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following scheme: you build an "empty" app that contains no activities, no settings - only the manifest, the icon for "manage apps" list and the native lib that is installed by the system in /data/data/*package*/lib directory.

This native library may, but doesn't have to expose JNI functions. In a typical situation, this lib will be a straightforward port of an opensource LGPL library - e.g. libdmtx.so.

The "client" apps will call **loadLibrary()** for the "external" lib, and after that it will call the usual **load()** for its JNI wrapper. This lib has the only purpose to translate Java methods to the public C APIs of the external lib.

The JNI wrapper and the corresponding Java class may be distributed as a .jar or as sources, they are not bound by LGPL license of the external lib.

Such scheme is, IMHO, the only way to ensure LGPL compliance on Android: anybody can recompile the "external" lib from the open source, package it as an "empty" app and install it on their device.

Regarding your concern about concurrent access to the lib, I actually doubt that it is so important: the high end devices have four cores more powerful each than one core on cheaper devices. OTOH, it's easy to use Linux synchronisation methods, e.g. named pipes, to keep track of active instances.

Comment: Good analysis, +1! Further question: is it legal to call System.load to load a native library that is part of another apk?

Comment: What do you mean by "legal"? I don't think it is guaranteed that this technique will work on all future versions and flavours of Android.

Comment: Afaik, apk are independent "sandboxes", each with its own user permissions. On the devices I have the /data/data/com.my.app/lib has read permissions set, so I can load the libs contained in it from another app running with a different user ID. But is this valid for all android devices/environments?

Comment: As I said before, I have not seen an explicit commitment that the lib files will have all-read permission in future releases, but up to date this is universal. It is possible to create _public_ files on [external storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) or on internal storage, but these alternatives have their own limitations.